# Is there any file name limit for Primefaces File upload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Can any one let me know if there is any file name length limit for primefaces file upload component. Its version 5.

**Reason:**
When i try to attach a file with file name length more than 170 it is not detecting.

Comment: Could you elaborate `not detecting` a little bit more?

Comment: Well it also depends on your OS. If you're exceeding the limits of your platform for filenaming, you'll have problems

Comment: 170 chars? Seriously?

Comment: "Not Detecting" the selected seems to be ignored by the file upload component, the server call did not happen.

Comment: 1. I tried a file with filename "aonfcuonefiuunefiune-test file for attachmentsize and error listing - 92348210984730987240hfjienfeiwbefiuwbngfiwnrfinrwingfriwnfirwnfiwnrfijrwnmfinm-aonfcuonefiuunefiune-test.docx"
it dint detect the file itself.
2. I reduced the filename to 170 chars "aonfcuonefiuunefiune-test file for attachmentsize and error listing - 92348210984730987240hfjienfeiwbefiuwbngfiwnrfinrwingfriwnfirwnfiwnrfijrwnmfinm-aonfcuonefiuunefiune-t.docx" and it worked.
I am using it in IE8

Comment: Try a different browser. IE imposes a very strict limit on the overall size of an HTTP request, a limit that neither mozilla or chrome have

Comment: @HarishAravind - were you able to find the cause of this problem? I am facing the same.

Comment: @niksvp : Not sure - also no errors in console :( 
i just imposed a 150 Char limit in my app..